# Basic regex expression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'd like to replace angle brackets and spaces in a string. For example `@"< something >"` goes to `@"something"`. I'm currently trying:

```
NSString *s1 = @"< something >";
NSString *s2 =
[s1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[<> ]"
                              withString:@""
                                 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, s1.length)];
```

However I'm brand new to regular expressions and `@"[<> ]"` doesn't seem to work. What's the correct regular expression to use to remove angle brackets and spaces?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I dont believe `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` uses regex, it's just a simple find / replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the documentation for `NSRegularExpressionSearch`:

> You can use this option only with the rangeOfString:... methods.

So even if you had the right regex, you wouldn't be able to use it with this method.

For the situation you describe, it'll probably be easier to use `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` with a character set that includes '<' and ' '.

**Update:** Joshua Weinberg points out that you'd like to remove all occurrences of the characters '<', '>', and ' '. If that's the case, you'll want to look to NSRegularExpression's `-stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` method:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<> " options:0 error:&error];
NSString *s1 = @"< something >";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, s1.length);
NSString *s2 = [re stringByReplacingMatchesInString:s1 options:0 range:range withTemplate:@""];
```

(I haven't tested that, but it should point you in the right direction.)

Comment: Problem is trimming will only take them off the beginning and end, he needs to replace them throughout. NSRegularExpression is probably the best bet.

Comment: You referenced the documentation saying "You can use this option only with the rangeOfString:... methods", but the documentation continues, "and stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:" The second half of the sentence is the exact method he was using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that strips out the characters: `'<'`,`'>'`,`' '`

```
NSCharacterSet*mySet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<> "];

NSString *s1 = @"< something >";

NSArray * components = [s1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                          mySet];
NSMutableString * formattedS1 = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString * s in components) {
  [formattedS1 appendString:s];
}
NSLog(@"formatted string %@", formattedS1);
```

You can add whatever characters you need in the future to the first line